# Vector of Queues in Ada

Tags: collections, ada

The Element_Type of the Vector is not limited, while the Queue is. How to organize a Queue Vector?

```
   with Ada.Containers.Unbounded_Synchronized_Queues;
   with Ada.Containers.Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces;
   with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

   package Queue_Vector is

      package Integer_Queue_Interfaces is new
        Ada.Containers.Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces
          (Element_Type => Integer);

      package Integer_Queues is new
        Ada.Containers.Unbounded_Synchronized_Queues
          (Queue_Interfaces => Integer_Queue_Interfaces);

      package Queue_Vectors is new
        Ada.Containers.Vectors
          (Index_Type   => Positive,
           Element_Type => Integer_Queues.Queue);

   end Queue_Vector;
```

Comment: Anything that is publicly synchronized/protected is going to be limited, so your best approach is to make your own queue pkg that hides that limitedness. This will probably involve access types under the hood, but it's better to encapsulate and hide them than to spread them and their associated memory management throughout the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is uncomfortable, but compiles:

```
    type Integer_Queue_P is access Integer_Queues.Queue;

    package Queue_Vectors is new
      Ada.Containers.Vectors
        (Index_Type   => Positive,
         Element_Type => Integer_Queue_P);
```

You might want to make a smart pointer out of the `Integer_Queue_P` (as [here](https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-core/blob/7be06227856aac9ec3aade5a412ade84a1b41469/src/gnatcoll-refcount.ads#L62)), so as to make sure the actual `Queue` gets freed on overwrite or deletion of a `Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not take into account that access to protected queues in an unprotected vector is meaningless, vector must also be protected. So I made a secure object containing a Hashed_Map of Vectors to solve my problem.